# How to add an input not related to the model with Formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

For a subscription form, I need to have a field that is not mapped to my User object.

This field is only used to ask the user for an invitation code, that is checked against an invitations list in the create action of the controller, but not saved anywhere, and without a relation to this User object.

I tried :

```
<%= semantic_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :invitation_key, :input_html => {:name => 'invitation_key', :id => 'invitation_key'} %>
```

But it does not work.

What is the correct way to do this with Formtastic ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Melinda's answer is fine, but since the extra attribute is somewhat related to the User model, I would create an accessor on the User (actually, I'd create a Signup model, but that's a digression):

```
class User
  attr_accessor :invitation_key
end
```

Then modify your controller to either check `@user.invitation_key` or `params[:user][:invitation_key]`.

Comment: creating an accessor for the model only to add an extra input on a form sounds a bit iffy to me

Answer (score 9):

You could just do something like this instead of the f.input. I couldn't find a way to do it with a Formtastic-specific helper:

```
<li>
    <%= label_tag 'Invitation Key' %>
    <%= text_field_tag :invitation_key %>
</li>
```